# alternate to hidden element on form submission

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been using a hidden element on form submission to pass a value of some fields that I need. Someone recently told me this is an old school way and bad practice to use hidden form elements in the spring boot world. What is an alternative to hidden element on spring and spring boot area.

Comment: This question is vague. It might refer to using javascript on the client to keep data and make http requests.

Comment: i know this question is vague. So waiting for expert's view on this.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the values must always be send in the request to the server. I can not think of some better way to transmit values to the spring controller other than request parameters using hidden input elements.
The [spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) also uses simple input fields (although no hidden fields in that example).